# Converting deeply nested JSON response from an API call to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, response

I am currently having trouble parsing a deeply nested JSON response from a HTTP API call.

My JSON Response is like

```
{'took': 476,
 '_revision': 'r08badf3',
 'response': {'accounts': {'hits': [{'name': '4002238760',
     'display_name': 'Googleglass-4002238760',
     'selected_fields': ['Googleglass',
      'DDMonkey',
      'Papu New Guinea',
      'Jonathan Vardharajan',
      '4002238760',
      'DDMadarchod-INSTE',
      None,
      'Googleglass',
      '0001012556',
      'CC',
      'Setu Non Standard',
      '40022387',
      320142,
      4651321321333,
      1324650651651]},
    {'name': '4003893720',
     'display_name': 'Swift-4003893720',
     'selected_fields': ['Swift',
      'DDMonkey',
      'Papu New Guinea',
      'Jonathan Vardharajan',
      '4003893720',
      'DDMadarchod-UPTM-RemotexNBD',
      None,
      'S.W.I.F.T. SCRL',
      '0001000110',
      'SE',
      'Setu Non Standard',
      '40038937',
      189508,
      1464739200000,
      1559260800000]},
```

After I receive the response I am storing it in data object using json normalize

```
data = response.json()
data = data['response']['accounts']['hits']
data = json_normalize(data)
```

However after I normalize my dataframe looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxLs1.png)

My Curl Statement looks like this

```
curl --data 'query= {"terms":[{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Account Type","query_term_id":"account_type","in_list":["Contract"]},{"type":"string","term":"status_group","in_list":["paying"]},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Region","in_list":["DDEU"]},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Country","in_list":["Belgium"]},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"CSM Tag","in_list":["EU CSM"]},{"type":"date_attribute","attribute":"Contract Renewal Date","gte":1554057000000,"lte":1561833000000}],"count":1000,"offset":0,"fields":[{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"DomainName","field_display_name":"Client Name"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Region","field_display_name":"Region"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Country","field_display_name":"Country"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Success Manager","field_display_name":"Client Success Manager"},{"type":"string","term":"identifier","field_display_name":"Account id"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"DeviceSLA","field_display_name":"[FIN] Material Part Number"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"SFDCAccountId","field_display_name":"SFDCAccountId"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Client","field_display_name":"[FIN] Client Sold-To Name"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Sold To Code","field_display_name":"[FIN] Client Sold To Code"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"BU","field_display_name":"[FIN] Active BUs"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Service Type","field_display_name":"[FIN] Service Type"},{"type":"string_attribute","attribute":"Contract Header ID","field_display_name":"[FIN] SAP Contract Header ID"},{"type":"number_attribute","attribute":"Contract Value","field_display_name":"[FIN] ACV - Annual Contract Value","desc":true},{"type":"date_attribute","attribute":"Contract Start Date","field_display_name":"[FIN] Contract Start Date"},{"type":"date_attribute","attribute":"Contract Renewal Date","field_display_name":"[FIN] Contract Renewal Date"}],"scope":"all"}' --header 'app-token:YOUR-TOKEN-HERE' 'https://app.totango.com/api/v1/search/accounts'
```

So ultimately I want to store the Response in a dataframe along with the field names.

Comment: don't post pictures when you can post the actual code/response. Not much anyone can do to test your data/response with a pic. With that said, can you post your json response, I may have a solution for you, but need to test it?

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks. I have added in the JSON response in the question and removed the picture as suggested. The field display name in the curl statement which is the column name is also not present in the JSON response.

Comment: Perfect. As soon as I get to my laptop I can test it and post back.

Comment: @chitown88 did you find some to decipher the json response please? thanks

Comment: haven't had a chance. Should be able to work with it in about an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do this sort of thing a few times in the past (flatten out a nested json) I'll explain my process, and you can see if it works, or at least can then work the code a bit to fit your needs.

1) Took the `data` response, and completely flattened it out using a function. This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) was very helpful when I first had to do this.

2) Then it iterates through the flat dictionary created to find where each rows and columns are needed to be created by the numbering of the new key names within the nested parts. There are also keys that are unique/distinct, so they don't have a number to identify as a "new" row, so I account for those in what I called `special_cols`.

3) As it iterates through those, pulls the specified row number (embedded in those flat keys), and then constructs the dataframe in that way.

It sounds complicated, but if you debug and run line by line, you could see how it works. None-the-less, I believe it should get you what you need.

```
data = {'took': 476,
 '_revision': 'r08badf3',
 'response': {'accounts': {'hits': [{'name': '4002238760',
     'display_name': 'Googleglass-4002238760',
     'selected_fields': ['Googleglass',
      'DDMonkey',
      'Papu New Guinea',
      'Jonathan Vardharajan',
      '4002238760',
      'DDMadarchod-INSTE',
      None,
      'Googleglass',
      '0001012556',
      'CC',
      'Setu Non Standard',
      '40022387',
      320142,
      4651321321333,
      1324650651651]},
    {'name': '4003893720',
     'display_name': 'Swift-4003893720',
     'selected_fields': ['Swift',
      'DDMonkey',
      'Papu New Guinea',
      'Jonathan Vardharajan',
      '4003893720',
      'DDMadarchod-UPTM-RemotexNBD',
      None,
      'S.W.I.F.T. SCRL',
      '0001000110',
      'SE',
      'Setu Non Standard',
      '40038937',
      189508,
      1464739200000,
      1559260800000]}]}}}


import pandas as pd
import re


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

flat = flatten_json(data)                      


results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
    column = column.replace('_', '')

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
         name             displayname selectedfields0 selectedfields1  selectedfields2       selectedfields3 selectedfields4              selectedfields5  selectedfields6  selectedfields7 selectedfields8 selectedfields9   selectedfields10 selectedfields11  selectedfields12  selectedfields13  selectedfields14  took _revision
0  4002238760  Googleglass-4002238760     Googleglass        DDMonkey  Papu New Guinea  Jonathan Vardharajan      4002238760            DDMadarchod-INSTE              NaN      Googleglass      0001012556              CC  Setu Non Standard         40022387          320142.0      4.651321e+12      1.324651e+12   476  r08badf3
1  4003893720        Swift-4003893720           Swift        DDMonkey  Papu New Guinea  Jonathan Vardharajan      4003893720  DDMadarchod-UPTM-RemotexNBD              NaN  S.W.I.F.T. SCRL      0001000110              SE  Setu Non Standard         40038937          189508.0      1.464739e+12      1.559261e+12   476  r08badf3
```

Comment: Thanks @chitown88 works like a charm, if you happen to notice the output selectedfields13 or selectedfields14 appears in scientific form any chance to convert them to a floating point number so that the e+12 etc does not show up?

Comment: oh ya, I see that. I'll give that a look within the hour and get back to you

Comment: is it ok if those values are stored as strings? I changed them to floats, but for whatever reason it converts it to scientific notation regardless. Only way I can think of preventing that is to have it stored/printed as a formatted string

Comment: I would be using that field in an equation actually. Adding a number would give an excel date. Hence would need it as a numerical data type

Comment: then ya, not sure how to prevent that. I'm wondering if it's just a print out thing. But ya sorry, can't help you out there. It's a good question though, so try posting as a new question, so that it can get the views and someone else may have a solution.